# need to filter duplicate record from a particular selected records

Tags: mysql, sql

need to filter duplicate record  from a particular selected records

SQL table **site_metatag** and i am using **MySQL client version: 5.5.30**

```
metatag_id | store_id | name
    1          0        copyright   
    2          0        author  
    3          0        robots  
    4          0        googlebot   
    5          0        revisit-after
    6          0        google-site-verification    
    9          1        google-site-verification    
    8          1        revisit-after
    10         1        googlebot   
    11         1        robots
    12         2        googlebot
    13         2        robots
    14         2        google-site-verification
```

need those record from `store_id` in `1` and `0` but `name` will be unquie like 
distinct() function give uniqe all record , but i need record that not used more then 1 time

```
metatag_id | store_id | name
     1         0        copyright   
     2         0        author  
     3         0        robots
```

i try

```
SELECT * FROM site_metatag v 
where metatag_id NOT IN
(
   select metatag_id from site_metatag p where v.name=p.name
) 
AND v.store_id in (0,1)
```

but not working..

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (mysql, oracel, mssql)

Comment: i am using MySQL client version: 5.5.30

Comment: You tried distinct name ?

Comment: distinct() function give uniqe all record , but i need record that not used more then 1 time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT 
    metatag_id, store_id, `name`
FROM
    site_metatag v
group by `name`
```

Or this, if you want to group by number of occurrences(in this case 1 -> cnt = 1).

```
SELECT 
    metatag_id, store_id, v.`name`, a.cnt
FROM
    site_metatag v
        inner join
    (select 
        `name`, count(*) as cnt
    from
        site_metatag
    group by `name`
    having cnt = 1) as a ON (v.`name` = a.`name`)
group by v.`name`
```

Answer (score 0):

use distinct() function. see [Distinct MYSQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)

Comment: distinct() function give uniqe all record , but i need record that not used more then 1 time

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
SELECT * FROM site_metatag WHERE v.store_id in (0,1) GROUP BY name
```

Comment: It's a good practice to provide a little more details with your answer.